# Initialiser list not in order

Tags: c++, initialization, initializer-list

So I have made a class called `Dictionary` which inherits from a base `IEnumerable` and contains a member of type `List`. `List` has a `const unsigned int&` member that stores and exposes its item count.

This is `Dictionary`'s constructor.

```
Dictionary() : _list(), IEnumerable(_list.Count)
{ }
```

I pass the `const unsigned int&` from the "initialised" list to `IEnumerable`. The problem is, that `IEnumerable`'s initialiser is being called before `_list`'s (the member of type `List`) so I'm passing in an invalid reference.

Is there any way to force the member `_list` to be initialised before the base class `IEnumerable`?

Comment: How do you set `List`'s `Count` data member? It is a reference, so it must refer to something.

Comment: it gets set in _list's constructor. But that is called after the base

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Base classes are always initialized before direct members.  (And in fact, the order of bases and members in a mem-initializer-list does nothing - the order is always determined from the class definition.)

One workaround is to move your member to another base class.

```
struct HasList {
    List _list;
    // Might want custom constructors here.
};

class Dictionary
    : private HasList,
      public IEnumerable
{
    // ...
```

(This is one of the few helpful uses of `private` inheritance.)

Comment: Oh i get it. I like that! sounds inovative. I think i'll do that :)

Comment: Perfect! thanks again. It didn't even need any significant changes to existing code :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Base class constructors are called before inherited class' constructors.
2. Members are initialized in the order they're **declared** (that is usually in the header file), the order of the initialization list is irrelevant.